# one.one.one.one entry in ARP table

Tags: 18.04, arp

I added an IP address of 1.1.1.2/24 to esnp4s0f0 interface.
And sending ping to 1.1.1.1

Why does arp table show it as **one.one.one.one** and not simply 1.1.1.1 ??

```
root@testbed:~# arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.10.225           ether   00:0c:29:bc:3e:68   C                     eno3
10.250.0.4               ether   52:54:00:4d:7e:fe   C                     br1
one.one.one.one          ether   02:10:18:cc:9e:6c   C                     enp4s0f0
```

I don't remember adding a DNS entry of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter that you did not make a DNS entry, because you have used a public IP address instead of a reserved private IP address. Your arp command is doing a DNS lookup and getting the actual answer for the IP address. If you want to suppress DNS lookups then do `arp -n`.

Examples:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ nslookup one.one.one.one
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   one.one.one.one
Address: 1.1.1.1
Name:   one.one.one.one
Address: 1.0.0.1

doug@DOUG-64:~$
doug@DOUG-64:~$ nslookup 1.1.1.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa    name = one.one.one.one.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
1.1.1.in-addr.arpa      nameserver = ns3.cloudflare.com.
1.1.1.in-addr.arpa      nameserver = ns7.cloudflare.com.
ns3.cloudflare.com      internet address = 162.159.7.226
ns3.cloudflare.com      internet address = 162.159.0.33
ns3.cloudflare.com      has AAAA address 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:21
ns3.cloudflare.com      has AAAA address 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:7e2
ns7.cloudflare.com      internet address = 162.159.6.6
ns7.cloudflare.com      internet address = 162.159.4.8
ns7.cloudflare.com      has AAAA address 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:408
ns7.cloudflare.com      has AAAA address 2400:cb00:2049:1::a29f:606
```